# Sudoku solving strategy

Tags: logical-deduction, sudoku

I started solving the puzzle below and I got stuck at this point. 
I don't know how to continue solving this puzzle except using try and error.
Does anyone know of a strategy to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Hi. [Here in a similar question I've posted all Sudoku solving strategies.](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/30540/13190) I'm sure one or multiple of these solving strategies are helpful for your Sudoku.

Comment: @Bilal I've looked briefly at it and I think that unless you use brute force it can be solved further.

Comment: Try reading about the XY-wing. It should help you to eliminate a few possibilities which will allow you to go on to solve the whole puzzle. I'll post it in a spoiler in an answer.

Comment: @bilal can u just post the original given sudoku?

Comment: @Stubborn sorry but I didn't save the original game.

Comment: @bilal so u tell me the solution what I'd given, was it wrong?

Comment: @Stubborn as long as the puzzle in the image which bilal has given us has a solution (which it definitely does) then no mistakes have been made, and it is a valid sudoku puzzle. What you have done is unacceptable which was to replace numbers with your own - which means you must have swapped out at least one printed number.

Comment: Man just read above comment made by Bilal only , he himself is saying that he hasn't saved the original game.

Comment: @Stubborn: Question Asker was right. you can't replace numbers given in the puzzle because the are true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you decide to use a sudoku solver online to assist you (I recommend [this one](http://www.sudokuwiki.org/sudoku.htm) as it shows you the steps to solve it as well as having other pages explaining many sudoku solving techniques), here's your sudoku which you can just copy and paste:

> 792538641154000837368471295815249376647153982239867514083010009006080103001300008

I've already suggested reading up on the XY-wing technique in the comments as it will help you proceed onto the next step in this sudoku (in this case, more specifically, the Y wing). I also recommend writing all possibilities into the cells if you're really stuck as it can help you spot these techniques easier (although as you become a better solver, being able to spot them without doing so saves time).

If you still can't do it, I've included how it is used in the spoiler below:

> (I've used the solver recommended above to make these screenshots) 
>  Here is the sudoku with all of the possibilities written in:
>  [image: image 1]
>  Here is the Y-wing:
>  [image: image 2]
>  The logic:
>  J2: 2 $\implies$ H2: 7 and J5: 9 $\implies$ no possibilities in H4.
>  H6: 2 $\implies$ H2: 7 and J5: 9 $\implies$ no possibilities in H4.
>  Therefore, neither J2 nor H6 can be a 2, eliminating those possibilities from the cells. You can now fill in J2 and continue to solve the puzzle.

Comment: thank you. I wrote all the possibilities and try to solve it  but I didn't understand the x-y wing until you explain it