# Sudoku puzzle - where to go next?

Tags: sudoku

[image: screenshot from my mobile]

Above is a link to a half-solved sudoku puzzle. I tried to fully solve it but just cant figure out what to do now.

**Source: Sudoku-Branium studios
It is an app on google playstore.**

Comment: A *9* in the top left corner of the bottom right square.

Comment: @RickvanOsta; is that because a 7 would force the 7 in block 2,3?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Welp, I had a theory for it which had to do with the 5 in the top row. I seem to have forgotten why exactly that had to be a 9, but I tried solving the sudoku with the 9 in that place and everything seems to fit, which leaves me to believe that it's the correct position either way, haha.

Comment: Related: [techniques for solving a Sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30519/techniques-to-solve-this-sudoku-puzzle/30540#30540).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In column 9, the two squares at locations (6,9) and (8,9) can both contain only a 5 or a 7. Any other digit at either location would cause an immediate clash with a similar digit in its row or column.
>  It follows that one of them is 5 and the other is 7, and therefore that 5 and 7 cannot occur elsewhere in column 9. This technique is called a "naked pair". Location (3,9) can therefore only be an 8.
>  After that, everything is straightforward.

Comment: How do you reach the conclusion that (8,9) must have those numbers only?

Comment: @Sid Column 9 and row 8 together already contain all the other numbers, so only a 5 or 7 there would not cause a direct conflict.

Answer (score -1):

The key is in the row 7 and column 4.

> [image]

Comment: I think the question was about the 'next step' not the complete answer. Watching this image kinda spoils the puzzle for the OP.

Comment: @PL457, I don't think the OP asked for the next step. And I also don't see him complaining about my answer spoiling the puzzle for him, you might have the ability of mind reading :)

Comment: I dont want to complain or anything, but PL457 is right.