# Finding a number in this sudoku

Tags: sudoku

I have been trying this sudoku for nearly 5 hours now but im unable to find any number further...If anyone could help me out i would be really grateful..
[image]

Note: The numbers in black are the prefilled numbers.
      The numbers in blue are the ones i have found out.
      The numbers written in small and grey are the possible numbers that can go 
      in that particular box(as i have found out...there may be a mistake in 
      that :) )

Comment: Without giving away the complete solution: the 5 in the 3rd row must be either in the 7th or the 9th column. Whichever it is, we can exclude the 2nd row 7th column cell being a 5. The same logic can be used for other cells as well.

Comment: I put it through my own Sudoku solver, and it needed to make a guess at this point (though it did some more eliminations like @elias suggested). My solver handles "level 2" techniques, such as hidden/naked pairs and x-wing, but doesn't do "level 3" techniques such as triplets or swordfish. So this at least shows that it is a tricky one and that you haven't overlooked something simple.

Comment: Ahh yes thank you @elias and @ Jaap Scherphuis

Comment: Maybe any of the advanced techniques [in this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30519/techniques-to-solve-this-sudoku-puzzle/30540#30540) (X-Wing, Swordfish, XY-Wing, Colouring, Remote Pairs, XY-Chain, Forcing Chains, etc.) helps to strike out some possible candidate-digits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the 8th column, the 7 has to be in the middle box, so it can be removed from the 9th row.

> The really hard thing to see is that if the element in the 9th row and 8th column is 2, then either you cannot have any 2 in the 1st column, or in the 4th row. Hence this element has to be 1.

After that, the Sudoku is easily solved.